# Follow Button in SharePoint 2013 site sitecollection error dialogLoading15

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, error, follow

I have a sitecollection error when I click on "Follow" button. The error is

```
"Unable to get property 'showWaitScreenWithNoClose of undefined or null reference"
```

The error is occuring because of null value in "SP.Res.dialogLoading15" parameter.

In FolowSite.js file

```
         function follow() {
            waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
```

In the default.aspx, the code calling this function is as follows

```
   <a title="Follow this site and get back to it easily from your sites page." class="ms-promotedActionButton" id="site_follow_button" style="display: inline-block;" 
                    onmouseover="this.firstChild.firstChild.style.left='-217px'; this.firstChild.firstChild.style.top='-192px';" 
                    onmouseout="this.firstChild.firstChild.style.left='-218px'; this.firstChild.firstChild.style.top='-48px';" 
                    onclick="follow(); return false;" href="#">
```

For the site collections which has 'follow' button working, SP.Res.dialogLoading15 is not null.

Any ideas on what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for sp.js to be loaded. Use it as below:

```
function follow() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
        var waitingDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gautham, The same code works on other sitecollections. Is there a way to find out, why this site collection is failing?

Comment: Probably different masterpages or different custom javascripts and other branding changes etc.

Comment: @Gautham, They all use the same master pages, In the html code where the call is initiated, I dont see any code difference